# How to remove only the parent element and not its child elements in Python?

Tags: python, xml, dom

A similar question to the one in JavaScript

I have a xml and want to comment just the parent tag without its children
like in the example below:

```
<object id="12">
 <process name="Developer">
  <appdef>
   <attributes>
    <attribute name="X">
        <ProcessValue datatype="number" value="15" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute name="Y">
        <ProcessValue datatype="number" value="59" />
    </attribute>
   </attributes>
  </appdef>
 </process>
</object>
```

and comment just < object > tags

```
<!--<object id="12">-->
 <process name="Developer">
   <appdef>
     <attributes>
       <attribute name="X">
        <ProcessValue datatype="number" value="15" />
       </attribute>
       <attribute name="Y">
        <ProcessValue datatype="number" value="59" />
       </attribute>
     </attributes>
   </appdef>
 </process>
<!--</object>-->
```

I have a code to comment the tag but it comment all its children also.

Thank you very much I appreciate any help

Due to confusions I am attaching the whole code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom


xml = """\
  <bpr:release xmlns:bpr="http://www.blueprism.co.uk/product/release">
   <object id="0e694daf-836e-44a9-816a-9b8127abb7b2" name="Developer 2 
     ex" xmlns="http://www.blueprism.co.uk/product/process">
    <process name="Developer 2 ex" version="1.0" bpversion="5.0.33.0" 
      narrative="BO for automation the HTML page&#xD;&#xA;" type="object" 
       runmode="Exclusive">
        <appdef>
            <attributes>
                <attribute name="X">
                    <ProcessValue datatype="number" value="15" />
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="Y">
                    <ProcessValue datatype="number" value="59" />
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
        </appdef>
       </process>
      </object>
    </bpr:release>
    """

def comment_node(node):
    comment = node.ownerDocument.createComment(node.toxml())
    print(comment)
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(comment, node)
    return comment


doc = minidom.parseString(xml).documentElement

comment_node(doc.getElementsByTagName('object')[-1])

xml = doc.toxml()
```

Comment: I ran your code and it seems node does not contain any XML element

Comment: have you tried to call the function like this 

    comment_node(doc.getElementsByTagName('object')[-1])

Comment: I have updated the code stage, now it might be clearer. I want to comment just <object> tag